# How to plot a Real time graph in Zeppelin?

Tags: angularjs, scala, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use zeppelin to plot a realtime graph. I have doing a sentiment analysis on tweets on per minute . I am able to query statically and plot a graph. But i would like this to be done dynamically. I am new to zeppelin and do not have much knowledge about angularJS. What should be the correct approach to this problem?

```
 val final_score=uni_join.map{case((year,month,day,hour,minutes),(tweet_count,sentiment))=>(year, month, day, hour, minutes(sentiment/tweet_count).ceil)}


final_score.saveToCassandra("twitter", "score",writeConf = WriteConf(ttl = TTLOption.constant(1000)))

final_score.foreachRDD(score => {
val rowRDD =score.map{case(year,month,day,hour,minutes,sentiment) =>(year,month,day,hour,minutes,sentiment) }
  val tempDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD)

   z.angularBindGlobal("stream", parsed) //to bind parsed to stream.
   tempDF.registerTempTable("realTimeTable")
})
```

Doing a query on the above table , i am able to get the graph. But i would like to dynamically update the graph every minute in order to keep in sync with the sentiment score . 
Thanks prior. 
[update] the angular part for the zeppelin notebook are as follows:

```
%angular
<div id="graph"  style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div id="legendDiv"></div>
</div>
<script>
function initMap() {

var colorList = ["#fde577", "#ff6c40", "#c72a40", "#520833", "#a88399"]


var el = angular.element($('#stream'));

console.log("El is "+el) //returns el as object

angular.element(el).ready(function() {
    console.log('Hello')
    window.locationWatcher =el.$scope.$watch('stream', function(new, old){
console.log('changed');}, true)})
</script>
```

But running this code keeps returning the following error.

```
vendor.js:29 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '$watch' of  undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '$watch' of undefined
```

The spark version that i am using is 1.6
And Zeppelin is 0.6

Answer (score 7):

[spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) since version 0.6.3 support [Spark Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).

For a `structuredDataFrame` after aggregation, with the following code in one Zeppelin paragraph. The [OutputMode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes) can be either `append` or `complete` depends how the structureDataFrame is aggregated.

```
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._

val query = highcharts(
  structuredDataFrame.seriesCol("country")
    .series("x" -> "year", "y" -> "stockpile")
    .orderBy(col("year")), z, "append")
```

And the following code in the next paragraph. The chart in this paragraph will be updated when there are new data coming to the structureDataFrame.

```
StreamingChart(z)
```

Run following code to stop update the chart.

```
query.stop()
```

Here is the example generate structureDataFrame.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation","/usr/zeppelin/checkpoint")

case class NuclearStockpile(country: String, stockpile: Int, year: Int)

val USA = Seq(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
  1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
  27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
  26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
  24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
  22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
  10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104).
    zip(1940 to 2006).map(p => NuclearStockpile("USA", p._1, p._2))

val USSR = Seq(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
  4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
  15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
  33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
  35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
  21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000).
    zip(1940 to 2006).map(p => NuclearStockpile("USSR/Russia", p._1, p._2))

input.addData(USA.take(30) ++ USSR.take(30))
val structureDataFrame = input.toDF
```

And the following code can be simulate to update the chart. The chart will be updated when the following code run.

```
input.addData(USA.drop(30) ++ USSR.drop(30))
```

> NOTE: The example using Zeppelin 0.6.2 and Spark 2.0
>
> NOTE: Please check the [highcharts license](https://shop.highsoft.com/) for commercial usage

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. 
But the version of spark that i am using is 1.6 and zeppelin is 0.6.0 . 
Will your answer hold true for these versions? If not what should be the approach then.

Comment: For Spark 1.6, it needs to use normal DataFrame with some code to monitor the change which trigger the plot

Comment: I have added an update in the question to the angular paragraph. But it keeps returning the following error 

 '    vendor.js:29 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '$watch' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '$watch' of undefined'